# How to get console cursor back to the begining of line in R?

Tags: r, loops, console, controls

Sometimes I perform long lasting calculations in the loop. To get control of the progress I print current value of the loop variable. However it makes my console flooded with numbers.
I would like to move back cursor to the begining of console line after each printing. This would end with the last value of the variable only. That would be similar to  command without   on line printer.
Any idea on how to achieve that in R console?

Comment: In most programming languages, this is achieved by using `\r`. The so-called 'carriage return'. Note that backslash introduces an escape sequence, so `\r` is one char. I don't know R but in [this article](http://rfunction.com/archives/1866) it is used.

Answer (score 3):

as b2f correctly mentions in the comment use `\r` as in the example below

```
cat('hello world\rMinor')
Minor world
```

One thing to note though is that every command is assigned a new line in an interactive setting, so in interactive code this only works as part of a single command.